# Why am I getting a NullPointerException in this code?

Tags: java, android

I'm getting NullPointerException in the following inflation of fragment.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inf, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =  inf.inflate(R.layout.fragment_featured, parent, false);

    CardView cardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardView1);
    cardView.setOnCardClickListener(this); //Error in this row!
    cardView.setItemSpace(Utils.convertDpToPixelInt(getActivity(),20));

    MyCardAdapter adapter = new MyCardAdapter(getActivity());
    adapter.addAll(initData());
    cardView.setAdapter(adapter);
    FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    frag = new TestFragment();
    manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.contentView, frag).commit();

    return v;
}
```

Comment: please provide details with your question like your stacktrace and where the error points to

Comment: You cardView went null. Can you double check that there is cardview with id cardView1 in layout fragment_featured?

Answer (score 1):

If on click gives null this means that the id doesn't exist in the view, so you may have inflated a wrong layout for the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

This type of error happens when you point to the view's id on xml file from java code which do not exist. Easiest way to solve this error, just rename this id in java code and the corresponding id in xml file to something else but same. This will definitely help you.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely in this line :

```
cardView.setOnCardClickListener(this); //Error in this row!
```

cardView is null which means on this line :

```
CardView cardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardView1);
```

R.id.cardView1 either doesn't exist or you misspelled cardView1.

Post your xml code for the view.